# Where to store the credentials on iPhone (username or userId)?

Tags: ios

When I authenticate the user I need to store the userId (primary key) somewhere on the device so I can use it later on to pull other information related to the users like "getAccounts(userId)".

I am thinking I can use NSUserDefaults to store the userId?

Any recommendations?

UPDATE: One thing also I need to mention is that the userId is auto generated and auto increment like 3,4,5,6,7 and so on.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: Do you have it somehow protected that this method takes a token ? So user cannot really just increment a value to get other user info ?

Comment: Good question! Currently no I do not pass any token. I will change my methods to include the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping in NSUSerDefault it's ok - but you should not keep userId there.
Some people can manipulate that data, change userId and take control on someones else account.

Always keep login + password or generate some tokens after user authorizes to avoid keeping full credentials that can be stolen when user loses his phone for example.

Also you need to extend your API to always require token (or login, passowrd) for every single operation - otherwise it's too easy to hack into functions like "getAccounts(userId)"

For password the best will be keychain as other suggested or at least encrypt it before saving it to NSUserDefaults.

Of course what you proposed in your questions works as well - but it's really bad practice and none of the apps should be build this way, so treat my answer more as good practice advices.

Comment: Exactly.....you should avoid keeping userId and I suggest for sake of simplicity you just keep (login, password) in keychain and send to server for each operation.....

Answer (score 2):

NSUserDefaults is the easiest place to save quick bits of useful information like the username or various pieces of preferences.

If you are saving passwords, then you need to store them in the Keychain via [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Comment: Easiest is not always best idea :)

Comment: I agree it's not *always* the best idea; but for many apps, especially initial ones, it's pretty much the only way.